# ¿Cual es la función de las random seeds?

Tags: random, lenguaje-agnóstico

Estoy con kotlin creando un generador de contraseñas y me he topado con las seeds pero nunca he sabido exactamente que función tienen, ¿cual es la diferencia entre pasarle una seed a una función random con no pasarle nada? Supongo que internamente ya tendrá alguna, pero nunca lo he entendido bien.

Comment: en líneas generales al plantar una semilla en un generador pseudoaleatorio la secuencia es predecible, se utiliza generalmente para armar tests en base a tener la misma secuencia pseudoaleatoria cada vez que se corre

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Números pseudo-aleatorios y su semilla

Vamos a comenzar con la parte conceptual y diciendo que la traducción al español de **seed** es **semilla**.

Una semilla se utiliza por un algoritmo de **generación de números PSEUDO-aleatorios** para calcular el siguiente número.

Y es que las funciones de generación de números aleatorios son, después de todo, [funciones deterministas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_determinista). Cito a la Wikipedia:

> un algoritmo determinista es un algoritmo que, en términos informales, es **completamente predictivo** si se conocen sus entradas.

El artículo de la Wikipedia en inglés: [Pseudorandom number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) comienza diciendo:

> A pseudorandom number generator (PRNG), also known as a deterministic random bit generator (DRBG), is an algorithm for generating a sequence of numbers whose properties approximate the properties of sequences of random numbers. The PRNG-generated sequence is not truly random, because it is completely determined by an initial value, called the PRNG's seed (which may include truly random values). Although sequences that are closer to truly random can be generated using hardware random number generators, pseudorandom number generators are important in practice for their speed in number generation and their reproducibility.

Mi traducción y énfasis de lo citado es:

> Un generador de números pseudo-aleatorios (GNPA), también conocido como **generador de bits aleatorios determinista** (GBAD), es un algoritmo para generar una secuencia de números **cuyas propiedades se aproximan a las propiedades de secuencias de números aleatorios**. La secuencia generada por GNPA **no es verdaderamente aleatoria**, porque **está completamente determinada por un valor inicial, llamado semilla de GNPA** (que puede incluir valores verdaderamente aleatorios). Aunque las secuencias más cercanas a las verdaderamente aleatorias se pueden generar utilizando generadores de números aleatorios de hardware, los generadores de números pseudo-aleatorios son importantes en la práctica por su velocidad en la generación de números y su reproducibilidad.

## ¿Qué significa, en la práctica, todo esto?

- Que la función sea determinista, podemos explicarlo así:

  - Si conoces la semilla inicial y el algoritmo utilizado para generar una secuencia de números pseudo-aleatorios, puedes reproducir completamente la secuencia. Es decir, no tiene nada de aleatoria, solo **parece** aleatoria. Una función realmente aleatoria no sería determinista.
  - Si llamas un millón de veces a un generador de números pseudo-aleatorios y el millón de veces le pasas un mismo valor de semilla, el millón de veces te va a devolver el mismo número
- Para generar secuencias de números, muchas funciones GNPA utilizan el valor obtenido en una ejecución como semilla para calcular el valor de la siguiente ejecución.
- Si bien la semilla y el resultado de la función de generación pseudo-aleatoria suele representarse por un número de coma flotante, de forma general, la semilla y el resultado no es más que una secuencia de bits que el algoritmo utiliza para generar una nueva secuencia de bits.
- Muchos entornos, para proveer secuencias únicas en cada ejecución derivan una semilla inicial de alguna combinación de valores que sea lo suficientemente única. Esto puede incluir la fecha y hora actual, información del sistema, etc.
- Algunas distribuciones de linux (y otros *nix) [implementan `/dev/random`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random), `/dev/urandom` y similares que *acumulan entropía* del ruido del sistema para generar semillas realmente aleatorias que luego son alimentadas a un GNPA para devolver números *realmente* aleatorios.
- [random.org](https://www.random.org/) ofrece *servicios* para obtener números realmente aleatorios.

## ¿Por qué nos con conformamos con números pseudo-aleatorios?

Para un computador común no hay una forma *real* de generar un número completamente aleatorio. Las computadoras son fantásticas haciendo cálculos que entregan resultados precisos y repetibles, pero el *pobre* procesador no tiene de donde tirar a la hora de pedirle un simple número aleatorio. Y es que los números aleatorios tienen algunas características estadísticas, principalmente que su distribución es uniforme.

Por ello es que, a través de la genialidad de algunas personas, hemos llegado al estado actual de las cosas. Los números pseudo-aleatorios son lo suficientemente buenos para ser indistinguibles de números realmente aleatorios.

La aproximación de *nix, de capturar *entropía*, por ejemplo, del ruido que se *escucha* por adaptadores Wifi y otras *fuentes* eléctricas es genial y la mejor aproximación que conozco para obtener números *impredecibles*.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta me queda más claro y ahora me siento engañado, ya que lo que se llama muchas veces aleatorio, realmente no lo es...

Comment: Te entiendo, aunque debo decir que la información siempre ha estado allí, tenía que picarte la curiosidad para llegar a ella. A todos nos pasa un poco esa _decepción_ cuando profundizamos en el tema, luego te das cuenta que, en realidad, es genial lo que _tenemos_ , no como lo pensabas antes, sino de otra manera. :)

Answer (score 0):

randomSeed(seed). Especifica un valor o semilla como el punto de inicio para la función random(). Este parámetro debe ser realmente aleatorio y para ello puede emplearse la función millis() o incluso analogRead() para leer ruido eléctrico desde una entrada analógica.